# Changing firstname and lastname on the checkout page without influencing the registration page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, css, customer-account, html

On the checkout page, you have the firstname and the lastname from the following code:

```
<li class="fields">
    <?php echo $this->getCustomerWidgetName()->toHtml(); ?>
</li>
```

But if you have a problem, the HTML code is already mounted from the file name.phtml and that same form is used on the new clients' registration page and I would need to make modifications to the same HTML and CSS.

How could I proceed so that I could make changes to it, without this influencing the new customer registration page (customer / account / create /)?

Comment: You mean to say same file (name.phtml) is calling on Registration and Checkout page?

Comment: That's right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `if`...`else` condition to differentiate it.

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$module = $request->getModuleName();  // Get Current Module Name
$controller = $request->getControllerName();  // Get Current Controller Name
```

For Customer Account Registration page - `customer` is module and `account` is controller name

whereas on Checkout page - `checkout` is module name and `onepage` is controller name

**For Example,**

```
<?php if($module=='checkout' && $controller=="onepage"): ?> 
    // Do your stuff
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Other way** is to use parent class to add your CSS only on checkout page

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I did not understand in detail what you meant.

Comment: please check my updated answer with condition. You can use it inside name.phtml file.

Comment: It worked very well. Thank you very much for all the help!

Comment: You're Welcome @MatheusPortela